# Pseudo Inverse Based on the Generalized SVD

Tags: linear-algebra

The Moore-Penrose inverse is only one of many possible pseudo-inverses. There are others that preserve different properties. The generalized SVD of two matrices, $A$, and $B$ is defined to have the form,

$$A = U_1\Sigma_1[X,0]V^\intercal$$

$$B = U_2\Sigma_2[X,0]V^\intercal$$

Is there a notion of a pseudo inverse that utilizes this GSVD decomposition, thereby utilizing the coupled structure?

Comment: I think that this is an interesting question. Ignoring the term with $X$ (and the pseudo-inverse): $B^{-1}=A^{-1}U_1\Sigma_1 \Sigma_2^{-1} U_2^T$. However, I believe that computing the GSVD takes more than $n^3$ steps, so there should be a numerical advantage in doing this. Did you follow up on it?